# Kendo UI Scheduler not avalaible in parameterMap AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

Well, I need to filter based on date range but when I use

`$scope.schedule.view().startDate()`

in parameterMap function isn't available, if I put it in $timeout it works, so how can I access to $scope.schedule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve it,

`$scope.schedule_options` isn't ready in DOM so you get `"undefined"` in parameterMap function, you need to set properties `autoBind: false` (prevent first call before DOM initializing) and when the event `$scope.$on("viewContentLoaded")` is resolve you can fire the method `dataSource.read();`

Regars,
Davide